# Android auto start service is not running on the device but it runs on emulator?

Tags: android, service, device, boot

The service is an auto start service. If I do run it in the emulator, it runs okay. But, when I install my application to an android device it does not run even after I reboot the device. Any suggestions in solving this issue?

Comment: can you upload code for more clarification ?

Comment: So it can run on your phone, it just doesn't auto-launch for you?

Answer (score 0):

i found no errors in codes however, i have tested the code on android 2.3.3 the service runs okay.
But using android 4.0 the service does not start automaticlly at boot up of the system